# Home network 10Gbpe speed issue

Tags: networking

I have had a 10Gbe network at my home for sometime now, I am using the NETGEAR 8-Port 10G, Cat7 cables all the way.  I have 4 devices hooked up to the network:

- Router (Running PFSense) - Dell Dual 10Gbe NIC
- R710 Server - Dell - Dual 10Gbe NIC
- Synology Diskstation DS1817 - Built in Dual 10Gbe Nic
- Desktop PC - Single Asus 10GBE Nic

When I do an iPerf3 test between any two of the devices (with the exception of the NAS as I can't), I get somewhere between 2Gbits/sec to 2.9Gbits/sec.

I have seen videos where people get faster speeds, in fact, near 10gbe.

Why can't I?  What is my bottle neck?  Is it my switch, and if so how can I tell?

Here are some screen shots of my Dell Server:

[image]
[image]

And a screen shot of my PC
[image]

What can I do next to determine why my speed is slow?

Comment: Have you tested between any device and the router? Or is this only always *via* the router? try using the [iperf3 --parallel](https://www.mankier.com/1/iperf3#--parallel) switch with a higher number than the default 2, as the default number of threads may not be enough to max the bandwidth.

Comment: It is from and to any device.

Comment: Have you tried hooking up your two fastest machines back-to-back without the switch, to eliminate the switch? Also, what TCP receive window is being used? If you force it to 1MiB, do you get better performance?

Comment: Have you tried a higher `--parallel` number?